# Getting datetime as a string in current timezone

Tags: timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

In the MySQL DB: `'2020-04-19 22:00:00'`(UTC). That's also what my endpoint returns since I set the connection option `dataStrings:true`.

On the client, after I fetch `date`:

```
const timezone = moment.tz.guess();

const convertedDate = moment(date)
   .tz(timezone)
   .format();
```

`convertedDate` then equals to `"2020-04-19T22:00:00+02:00"` (I'm in the UTC+2 zone).

I would like to get it in the format "2020-04-20T00:00:00" instead.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `moment(date)` believes your incoming `date` value is in local time, not UTC. So, your timezone conversion to local time changes nothing. You can tell `moment` it's UTC, like this:

```
const timezone = moment.tz.guess();

const convertedDate = moment.utc(date)
   .tz(timezone)
   .format();
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need moment-timezone for this.  With Moment by itself you can use the `utc` function when parsing, and the `local` function to convert to the user's local time zone before formatting.

```
moment.utc('2020-04-19 22:00:00').local().format()

//=> "2020-04-20T00:00:00+02:00"
```

Also, the Moment team recommends using Moment for existing projects only.  For new development, we recommend using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead:

```
luxon.DateTime.fromSQL('2020-04-19 22:00:00', {zone: 'utc'}).toLocal().toISO()

//=> "2020-04-20T00:00:00.000+02:00"
```